# Workflow Rule to send email alert

Tags: salesforce, workflow

I need a work flow rule which should satisfy below conditions
email should be sent to lead owner when a Specific__user(specific user i have here) creates a lead
and email should be sent when Specific__user changes lead owner

To send email i have email alert designed already.
Using below but it is not working
Rule criteria: created, and every time it's edited
AND(ISCHANGED( OwnerId ), PRIORVALUE( OwnerId) = 'Specific__user_Id')

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same email to be sent for the following conditions, try using the formula below.

1. Send email when a specific user creates a Lead.
2. Send email when a specific user changes a the Lead Owner of an existing Lead.

   OR(
   AND(
   ISNEW(),
   CreatedBy.Id = Specific__user_Id
   AND(
   ISCHANGED(OwnerId),
   $User.Id = Specific__user_Id
   )
   )